# Calling string from one function into another doesent seem to work., why?

Tags: javascript

So I have this code and it does not seem to work. The thing I want it to do is to call the "together" from the function "go" in the function "second". What am i doing wrong?

The program was initially supposed to take what is in the input-text and add it with the ".com" or the ".no"(depending on what u checked) and redirect to that page. But I only want to call the "together" in the "second" function. Is there any better way to do it?

```html
<!doctype html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>A Basic Form</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css"> 

</style> 
</head> 
<body>


<fieldset>
 <legend>Redirection: </legend>
  <div>
   <label>Where do you want to go?</label>
   <input type="text" id="input" name="input" size="7">
   <input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="go()">
  </div>
  <div>
   <input type="radio" id="no" name="end" value=".no">
   <label for="no">.no</label><br />
   <input type="radio" id="com" name="end" value=".com">
   <label for="com">.com</label>
   
  </div>
</fieldset>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var end = "";
 var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
 
 function go(end, input){
  
  if (document.getElementById("no").checked){
   end = document.getElementById("no").value;
  }else if (document.getElementById("com").checked){
   end = document.getElementById("com").value;
  }else{
   alert("Please Choose a category!"); 
  }
 
  var together = input + end;
  // window.location.replace("http://www." + together);
  }
  second(together);
  
 function second(together){
  alert(together);
 }
 
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: The brace { before second(together); should be removed.

Comment: This can be avoided if you would use an editor or IDE which supports javascript code analyzer and you would have seen the syntax error :)

Comment: What kind of editor or IDE? Name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function go(end, input){

    if (document.getElementById("no").checked){
        end = document.getElementById("no").value;
    }else if (document.getElementById("com").checked){
        end = document.getElementById("com").value;
    }else{
        alert("Please Choose a category!"); 
    }

    var together = input + end;
    // window.location.replace("http://www." + together);
    } // remove this        
    second(together);
} // add this
```